# Jquery .click() doesn't work after html has been changed

Tags: onclick, jquery, replacewith

It's pretty basic, I have a button, and when you click it, it changes. But after it changes the `.click()` event doesn't work on it, but works on divs that are already on the page

```
$('#editBioButton').click(function(){
       /* this captures html text and replaces it with textbox */
           var oldBio = $('.bioText').html();
        $('.bioText').replaceWith(' <textarea name="newBio" rows="6" cols="30" > ' + text + ' </textarea>');
       /* this switches button */
        $('#editBioButton').replaceWith(' <div id="saveBioText"> Save Changes </div> ');
       /* this div won't react when clicked */
        $('#saveBioText').click(function(){
           alert('itowrks');
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem before. Turns out jQuery loses all bindings on elements that are added after loading. You should use the `delegate` method

```
$("#editBioButton").delegate("#saveBioText", 'click', function(){
  alert("this.");
});
```

Comment: More accurately, there are no event handlers bound to elements that are added to the DOM in the future. If you bind now, the binding only affects elements currently in the DOM. If you replace an element with another one, the event handler(s) bound to the replaced element will be lost, and not applied to the new element.

Comment: `$(document).on("click", "#saveBioText", function(){
    alert('this');
});`

worked for me. Had problems with `delegate`, anyhow, problem solved one way or another (:

Comment: Yes, @marczking has the best answer $(document).on !

Comment: Yeah, `.on` is the preferred way. I added this as an answer now so people are more likely to find this then the comment. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#editBioButton').click(function(){
    var oldBio = $('.bioText').html();
    $('.bioText').replaceWith(' <textarea name="newBio" rows="6" cols="30" > ' + text + ' </textarea>');
    $('#editBioButton').replaceWith(' <div id="saveBioText"> Save Changes </div> ');
    $(document).on('click', '#saveBioText', function(){
        alert('it works');
    });
});
```

Comment: I agree, but there is a search function, and you only need to read around two answers about this problem before you find out about the .on() function?

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
$(selector).live('click',function(){ });
```

Comment: `.live()` is depreciated as of jQuery 1.7 and `.delegate()` was preferred over `.live()` as of jQuery 1.4.2. Reference: http://api.jquery.com/on

Answer (score 1):

The **click** method doesn't work on element added after that the page is been loaded, instead you can use the **live** method with **click** event

```
$("#editBioButton").live('click', function(){
   ...
});
```

Comment: `.live()` is depreciated as of jQuery 1.7 and `.delegate()` was preferred over `.live()` as of jQuery 1.4.2. Reference: api.jquery.com/on

Comment: I didn't know that it was deprecated, but recently I'm using .on()

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way to write this is by using `on`:

```
$(document).on("click", "#saveBioText", function() {
  alert('this');
});
```